# java.security.AccessControlException on creating XWPFDocument with *.docx with an checkbox control

Tags: java, apache-poi, lotus-domino

I use XWPFDocument to create letters.

I fill the Boookmarks in the letters with IBM-Notes data.
To create an XWPFDocument i use this 3 code lines.

```
try { 
    //Open java.io.File and java.io.FileInputStream.
    File file = new File(filename); 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
    XWPFDocument xwpfDoc = new XWPFDocument(fis); 
}
```

The line XWPFDocument xwpfDoc = new XWPFDocument(fis) normally gives me a readable XWPFDocument.
But at the moment that the *.docx Files contains an checkBox or some other control we get an AccessControlException.

Full Exception:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.security.AccessControlException:
 Access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:203)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:123)
```

Is it possible to use XWPFDocument to read(and write)docx files with controls and how or should we avoid *.docx files with controls like checkboxes?

Thanks John,

Comment: Have you turned on some non-standard Java permissions / security settings on your JVM?

Comment: It look likes that's the Java permission indeed is the issue. 
So we need more permissions for opening an *.docx file with controls in it.  
Thank you.